# Print only lins that matching couple of words in GREP

Tags: grep

How to print only lines of text file which contain for example word "car" or word "house" with GREP? I know how to do it but only with one word:

```
grep "car" input.txt > output.txt
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to grep for two (or more) words instead of one... where string contains "foo" OR string contains "bar".  Try this:

`cat input.txt | grep -i -E "car|house" > output.txt`

You can put other things in there as well: `"car|house|cat|mouse"` etc.  It doesn't have to be limited to only two things.

Comment: Note that it is not necessary to use `cat`, you can directly do `grep ... input.txt`.

Comment: agreed.  I am not entirely sure why, but I prefer this method.  Maybe because I can easily see what file I am searching through?  Or maybe because it has a more logical implied program flow.  In any case, yes, @fedorqui, you are correct.  It is unnecessary to necessarily use `cat`

Answer (score 0):

`grep "car\|house" input.txt > output.txt`